# How do I async await multiple promises in parallel? [Syntax Error: await is a reserved word]

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I am querying some data from [airtable](https://airtable.com/appGI25cdNsGR2Igq/api/docs#curl/table:authors:retrieve) which is basically a database of books and related authors. Each book record has an `authorId` field which I have to query separately to fetch related author data.

Here is how I get all books first:

```
let books = await axios.get("https://api.airtable.com/v0/appGI25cdNsGR2Igq/Books?&view=Main%20View")
let authorIds = books.data.records.map( ( book) => book.fields.Author[0] )
```

This works and I get these author ids:

```
[ 'recNLaQrmpQzfkOZ1',
  'recmDfVxRp01x85F9',
  'recKQqdJ9a2pHnF2z',
  'recKMiDhdCUxfdPSY',
  'rec67WoUDFjFMrw44' ]
```

Now I want to send this data to a `getAuthors` function like this:

```
const getAuthors = async (authorIds) => {
  authorIds.map( id => await Promise.all([
    return axios.get(`https://api.airtable.com/v0/appGI25cdNsGR2Igq/Authors/${id}`
  ])))
}
```

This function is supposed to get me my related author data but instead I get an error:

```
Syntax Error: await is a reserved word
```

...on this line: `authorIds.map( id => await Promise.all([...`

What am I doing wrong and is there a way to fix this?

Comment: My babel setup works fine, I am using next.js which preconfigured for transpilation etc. Also the first request for books works just fine which means async is not a problem

Comment: updated the line on which I get the error: `authorIds.map( id => await Promise.all([`

Comment: Why would you need async/await + Promises ? Those are two different patterns to manage async code.

Comment: @Booster2ooo Because you cannot use `async`/`await` without promises? They're not different at all, it's just syntactic sugar for `then`+callbacks.

Comment: hint: you can only `await` in a function that is `async`

Comment: @Bergi thanks, I wasn't aware about the nature of await\async in JS, I was still wondering the use for it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have placed the `await` in the `map` callback function, not in the one that is declared as `async`. You'll want to use

```
async function getAuthors(authorIds) {
  await Promise.all(authorIds.map(id =>
    axios.get(`https://api.airtable.com/v0/appGI25cdNsGR2Igq/Authors/${id}`)
  ));
}
```

Though probably better replace the `await` by `return`.